# Rails: mass assignment false negative and redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variable-assignment

Based on a previous Q&A on StackOverlfow, I added the following to application.rb:

```
 config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

as I was getting errors of the type Can't mass-assign protected attributes

After I did that, it seemed as if everything was working fine. I am now getting that same error, but it's a false negative. Note that even though I am getting an error, the column is actually updated.

Here's the debugger output:

```
Started PUT "/categories/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-09 11:26:40 -0700
Processing by CategoriesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SifcfX29c+mGRIJXvUWGnZ8mBelMm4uZloYsoO317SY=", "admin_selections"=>{"admin1"=>"56", "admin2"=>"55", "admin3"=>"", "admin4"=>"", "admin5"=>"", "admin6"=>"", "admin7"=>"", "admin8"=>""}, "category"=>{"update_admins_field"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Category", "id"=>"5"}
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE `categories` SET `admins` = '[\"56\",\"55\",\"\"]', `updated_at` = '2012-07-09 18:26:40' WHERE `categories`.`id` = 5
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, category, commit, action, controller, id):
  app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:74:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:62:in `update'
```

It seems as if the MySQL code is properly generated, but then there's a rollback and 500 error.

Here's the relevant code from categories_controller.rb:

```
def update
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format| #this is line 62
    if params[:category][:update_admins_field]
      params['admins'] = return_admins_json (params)
      if @category.update_attribute(:admins,params['admins'])
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' } #line 66
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    else
      format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was not successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end

    if @category.update_attributes(params)  #line 74
      format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Why is it getting to line 74? should't the user have been redirected at line 66? Why am I also getting an error when the update takes place?

Comment: Shouldn't line 74 read: `if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])` instead?

Comment: This is an update operation, and the model will use the entire params structure to update the record in line 74. This is correct syntax. The earlier conditional code, is set into motion if I am updating only the admins column.

Comment: The reason the second if statement was executed, is that it's part of the respond_to_format block. I neglected to make the first and second if blocks conditional relative to the parent respond_to_format. Not separating out the category object from the params object was resulting in a request to update attributes that do not exist (utf8, method, etc.).

Comment: PS: you need to accept the answer so I can mark it as complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set whitelist_attributes to true, and use attr_accessible in each model for security reasons. Here is information on that:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Also, read Niiru's commment above.

Edit:

In your control flow, I think its not doing what you want. If it gets to line 74, it probably passed the first if conditional

```
if params[:category][:update_admins_field]
```

And then failed the second if

```
if @category.update_attribute(:admins,params['admins'])
```

And then exited that if/else/end and continued to line 74 as no return had been called yet. To fix this, I think you want something like this:

```
if admin category
   if update admin
      return success
   else
      return failure
   end
else
   if update normal
      return success
   else
      return failure
   end
end
```

Comment: whitelist_attributes was set by default to true (Rails 3.2.3) following the attach on GitHUB. See my comment to niiru.

Comment: see updated answer above. I hope it helps. I also strongly urge ya to work with rails to protect your attributes and use attr_accessible and whitelisting.

Comment: I will test this. I am using attr_accessible, but the problem is when I was trying to save only one attribute, it was thinking that 'method', 'utf8', etc. are also attributes (see error message).

Comment: hence niiru's comment. Choose which params to pass to the update attribute, specifically params[:category]. Here is a tutorial about user sign-up but it is the same idea: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec:using_form_for